# MongoDB w Node.js Driver: Writing Syslog Messages to Collection - Iterate or Stream?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-streams

I have a syslog collector implemented in Node.js and want to save these syslogs to a MongoDB collection. The issue is that these syslogs arrive in chunks of dozens at a time.

What is the best way to handle writing that to the database? It seems like what I would like to do is write these several per connection to the database instead of opening and closing a database connection for each syslog message received.

Even better would be to keep a connection to the database open and write each syslog as it arrives.

Is a batch write the way to go here? Basically fill an array in memory that get's emptied every x seconds? In other words `.insertMany` every x seconds?

Or, is there a way to keep a connection open to Mongo for several `.insertOne`'s?

I need to slightly modify the syslog text prior to inserting it into the database collection. Does this mean I should use a Readable and Writable stream, or does a Writable stream alone work ok? The syslogs are coming in over UDP.

Answer (score 0):

After researching, the correct way to do this is to simply keep the database connection open for the lifetime of your service/app. Basically just insert as records come in. No need to implement a stream beyond what the UDP datagram service already did.